# Error in IF statement

Tags: r

I am trying to construct an if statement that will calculate a statement if the divisor is greater than zero and return a zero if not.
I'm certain I have the curly braces in the right places but R keeps giving me a warning message saying that

> the condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used.

I understand this means R is only evaluting the first statement and ignoring the else bit, but I know from my data that there are certainly zero entries for the variable in the if condition

Here is my current code

```
if (contributions$MEMCONTAMT > 0) {
 contributions$CONTAMTRATIO <- contributions$EMPCONTAMT/contributions$MEMCONTAMT
} else {
 contributions$CONTAMTRATIO==0
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at `?ifelse`, which is vectorised.

Comment: Guess you want either `=` or `<-` for the else line. Not `==`

Comment: Suggest to provide sample data and fuller body of code.

Comment: The variable MEMCONTAMT is a numeric variable taking any value. I've used the summary command and it has a min value of -44 and a max value of 740. There are no N/A

Comment: I assume you want to return a zero for each element of `contributions$MEMCONTAMT` that is less than or equal to 0, right? If so, you should be able to just do: `contributions$CONTAMTRATIO <- ifelse(contributions$MEMCONTAMT > 0, contributions$EMPCONTAMT/contributions$MEMCONTAMT, 0)`

Comment: Bingo - thanks jbaums. that does exactly what I need

Comment: Slightly shorter: contributions$CONTAMTRATIO <- with(contributions, ifelse(MEMCONTAMT > 0, EMPCONTAMT/MEMCONTAMT, 0))

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for

```
transform(contributions, 
          CONTAMTRATIO = "[<-"(EMPCONTAMT / MEMCONTAMT, MEMCONTAMT <= 0, 0))
```